Best aria-label for hamburger menu?
I have a hamburger menu that expands and collapses a sidebar menu when clicked.
The expanded version shows menu items with labels, while the collapsed version just shows icons.
What would be the best aria-labels for this hamburger menu?

It mainly depends on the level of the menu, but
Menu or Navigation is a good way to go.
The GOV.UK Design System uses a button that is labelled “Menu” visually, as it’s known that icons often are not understood.

The French State’s Design System also uses “Menu” as the label for the burger icon.

Bootstrap’s Navbar uses Toggle navigation as the label.
A button that expands or collapses another piece of content, like a menu, exposes its state to assistive technology via ARIA, so it’s not necessary to add the state to the label.
A screen reader would announce the following when the button receives focus.

Menu, button, collapsed.

Another important details is that both Bootstrap’s and GOV.UK’s examples place the burger button inside the navigation landmark, which helps provide context for assistive technology.

Navigation, landmark.
Menu, button, collapsed.


Because aria-label is aimed at screen reader users, consider how the menu is perceived through screen reader software. Maybe you can provide a single menu, labeled with "Main menu" and leave the switch to an alternative view only perceivable for people with normal vision.

When the sidebar is collapsed:
aria-label="Expand menu"

This label informs users that activating the button will expand the menu to show labels.
When the sidebar is expanded:
aria-label="Collapse menu"

This label informs users that activating the button will collapse the menu to show only icons.
Of course you can adapt the message to your taste.
However, one thing to mention: if you're using something like bootstrap, you need to add aria to the button itself, this time it has to be hidden. Like this:
<i class=”fa fa-bars” aria-hidden=”true”></i>


Thanks! The only difference when the menu is expanded vs collapsed is the collapsed version still shows visible menu items, although the icons don't have labels. Do you think it's still necessary to communicate that the menu is collapsed vs expanded?

for the icons you don't need aria, just use alt

A button which will expand or collapse a region must have the aria-expanded attribute, which the screen reader will anounce. Adding the state in the label is redundant.

"Must" is not the same as "having." Accessibility isn't a field that developers pay much attention to; it's not exactly a secret.
